# Rails 5 actioncable ping disable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I see that the actioncable is sending a ping about every 3 seconds to all open websocket connections. It seems that the ping is send from here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/app/assets/javascripts/action_cable/connection_monitor.coffee

How can I disable the ping of the actioncable?

Comment: What is the purpose of removing the ping? Becuase ActionCable uses this ping to check if the connection is connected. If the server doesn't receive the ping then it tries to reconnect the connection.

Comment: Initially for educational purposes and to see how far I can tweak it.